# Pagination with users

Tags: pagination

How do I get pagination set up with the following? It should be easy but I'm getting in a muddle.

```
{% set myUserQuery = craft.users().group('members').order('companyName asc').limit(10).find %}
{% set users = myUserQuery %}


<div class="col-24 gutter-bottom--none flex-container">

  {% for user in users %}
      {% include "includes/_directory-list" %}
  {% endfor %}

</div>

{% include "includes/_pagination" %}
```

---

I thought I might be able to do this, but no

```
{% paginate users %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% paginate myUserQuery as users  %}

{% for user in users %}

{% endfor %}
```

[This should help you](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/tags/paginate.html#showing-the-elements) also.